# DocuSign ID Check createRecipient does not generate ActivateSecurityChecks.aspx url

Tags: docusignapi

I managed to create an Envelope with "ID Check $" in the Docusign sandbox and it generates the email notification with a link that looks like this

https://demo.docusign.net/Signing/ActivateSecurityChecks.aspx?....

When I call createRecipient the resulting url looks like this and it goes straight into signing, skipping the ID Check

https://demo.docusign.net/Signing/StartInSession.aspx?...

The documentation for "createRecipient " states <<"Your application is responsible for authenticating the identity...">>

Is there an API that can generate the first link?

Here is the payload for the createEnvelope

```
<ds:envelopeDefinition xmlns:ds="http://www.docusign.com/restapi">
 <ds:status>sent</ds:status>
 <ds:emailSubject>EMAIL SUBJECT</ds:emailSubject>
 <ds:compositeTemplates>
  <ds:compositeTemplate>
   <ds:serverTemplates>
    <ds:serverTemplate>
       <ds:sequence>1</ds:sequence>
       <ds:templateId>TEMPLATE ID</ds:templateId>
     </ds:serverTemplate>
    </ds:serverTemplates>
    <ds:inlineTemplates>
     <ds:inlineTemplate>
      <ds:sequence>1</ds:sequence>
      <ds:recipients>
       <ds:signers>
        <ds:signer>
         <ds:email>RECIPIENT EMAIL</ds:email>
         <ds:name>RECIPIENT NAME</ds:name>
         <ds:recipientId>1</ds:recipientId>
         <ds:roleName>Signer 1</ds:roleName>
         <ds:requireIdLookup>true</ds:requireIdLookup>
         <ds:authenticationMethod>KnowledgeBasedAuth</ds:authenticationMethod>
         <ds:RequireIDLookupSpecified>true</ds:RequireIDLookupSpecified>
         <ds:idCheckConfigurationName>ID Check $</ds:idCheckConfigurationName>
        </ds:signer>
       </ds:signers>
      </ds:recipients>
     </ds:inlineTemplate>
    </ds:inlineTemplates>
  </ds:compositeTemplate>
 </ds:compositeTemplates>
</ds:envelopeDefinition>
```

Here is the payload for the createRecipient

```
 <ds:recipientViewRequest xmlns:ds="http://www.docusign.com/restapi">
  <ds:envelopeId>ENVELOPE ID</ds:envelopeId>
  <ds:userName>RECIPIENT NAME</ds:userName>
  <ds:email>RECIPIENT EMAIL</ds:email>
  <ds:authenticationMethod>KnowledgeBasedAuth</ds:authenticationMethod>
  <ds:recipientId>1</ds:recipientId>
  <ds:returnUrl>OUR URL</ds:returnUrl>
 </ds:recipientViewRequest>
```

Comment: Can you provide an API log of your envelope creation call? It sounds like you're not correctly defining the recipient auth.

Comment: I edited the original post with more details.  Please notice that the link contained in the email notification works but the link generated by the createRecipient does not.  May be something is missing in the createRecipient request.

Comment: @Drew, are you saying that the link generated by API createRecipient  should trigger the authentication?.   Clearly the link in the email generated by DocuSign does.

Answer (score 0):

Mystery solved.

You need to set embeddedRecipientStartURL = SIGN_AT_DOCUSIGN and set clientUserId to the same value you have in the signer. The resulting URL triggers ID Check, KnowledgeBasedAuth, Lexus Nexis  authentication.

```
 <ds:recipientViewRequest xmlns:ds="http://www.docusign.com/restapi">
  <ds:envelopeId>ENVELOPE ID</ds:envelopeId>
  <ds:userName>RECIPIENT NAME</ds:userName>
  <ds:email>RECIPIENT EMAIL</ds:email>
  <ds:authenticationMethod>KnowledgeBasedAuth</ds:authenticationMethod>
  <ds:recipientId>1</ds:recipientId>

  <ds:clientUserId>1</ds:clientUserId>
  <ds:embeddedRecipientStartURL>SIGN_AT_DOCUSIGN</ds:embeddedRecipientStartURL>

  <ds:returnUrl>OUR URL</ds:returnUrl>
 </ds:recipientViewRequest>
```